# asp .net mvc 4 Entity Framework database first override model property type

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Using C#, ASP .Net MVC 4, Entity Framework 5 and Database First. How can I override a property or add a new property to a model class? Below you can see the "Type" as a Byte, but I can't display the byte to the users and I want to display a friendly name. The Type description is not in the database, it is stored in a dictionary.

```
namespace Cntities
{
  public partial class myClass
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public byte Type { get; set; }    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the class is a partial you can expand and add your own properties and methods just ensure its defined in the same location as your current partial file.

```
namespace Cntities
{
public partial class myClass
{
    public string DisplayValue{ get {
          return "Formated"; // An example
    }
}
}
```

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx