# Change data on DataGridView without change its source

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I have job class numbers stored on the database and want to show my data in "DataGridView" by replacing the job class numbers with job class name.

I use Entity Framework and retrieve data from the database to a generic list.

I try to create DataTable and bound the DataGridView to it.

Is this way correct?

In my code below I want to determine the column that is used in DataTable but it does not work properly if I remove column names ("ID", "Nme", "jobClass" ... ) it work and show all columns in DataGridView but with add column names I get reeor.

[image]

`

```
IEnumerable<Employee> employeesList = new List<Employee>();
                employeesList = db.EmployeeRepository.GetAllEmployees();


                DataTable employeesTable = new DataTable();
                using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(employeesList,"ID", "Name", "jobClass", "College", "Department" ))
                {
                    employeesTable.Load(reader);
                }

                
                dgvEmployees.DataSource = employeesTable;
```

`

Comment: Are you turning the "List<Employee>" list into a dataTable just because you don't want to show all the "Employee" fields in the DGV? Is this the goal?

Comment: No, my first problem is I want to change the "job class" from number to job class name (string). So I tried to use the DataTable as a medium

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using Json to do the conversions.

You will convert your main object to Json and then convert it into a DataTable:

```
string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employeesList);
employeesTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(data);
```

To define the fields you want in the DataTable, in your "Employee" object, mark the fields you don't want in the DataTable with the attribute "[JsonIgnore()]", as in the example below:

```
public class Employee
{
    [JsonIgnore()]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string jobClass { get; set; }
    public string College { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use partial class to change my data model and solve my problem.
see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960513/asp-net-mvc-4-entity-framework-database-first-override-model-property-type)
[and this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods?redirectedfrom=MSDN)